# kendo ComboBox find and select value if exists

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a kendo combobox, and also have a variable with a value.
How can I search for the value in the combobox, and if exists, select it?
All with javascript/Jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/mspasiuk/8HnnZ/

```
var movieId=10;


var combo =$("#movies").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    height: 100
});
```

I can't find how to set the value having and Id. 
So my question is how to set the selectedIndex or Value to the one I have, and if is not exists, set the selectedIndex to -1

Comment: if you can provide a code sample of what you have at the moment. Then I should be able to give a better answer.

Comment: @DavidShorthose thanks for replying, I edit my question and also added a jsfiddle

Comment: have added some more info and updated your fiddle. Alerts are there just to show you what is happening.

Answer (score 5):

1) You need to subscribe for change event first to accommodate changed value.

```
var widget = $("#movies").data("kendoComboBox");
```

2) In change event you can now code for find and select existing value.

```
widget.bind("change", function() {
  if (widget.selectedIndex === -1 && widget.value()) {
      if (widget.dataSource.view().length > 0) {
          widget.select(0)  
      } else {
          widget.value("");                          
      }
  }
});
```

Click [Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/OZEV) to see the demo.

Answer (score 3):

this link should help you with what you need.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/api

it shows you all the important sections relating to accessing the "under the covers" areas of the api.

edit:

Have updated you fiddle with a possible solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/8HnnZ/5/

```
 var movies =  $("#movies").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: data,
        height: 100
    });

$("#setValue").click(function() {
    var setme =  $("#movies").data("kendoComboBox"); 
    setme.value(movieId);
    if(setme.selectedIndex == -1) {
        alert('not allowed'); 
        setme.select(-1);
        setme.value('');
        alert(setme.selectedIndex);
    }
});
```

This does it based on a button being clicked but should give you an idea of how to set it up for your needs.